# How to print part of value in json data by using dart

Tags: json, dart

right now I am working in dart. I have json data like this:

```
{
  "name":"firstName lastName",
  "address": "myAddress"
}
```

I wanna ask...is there a possibility to print only `firstName` without `lastName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var name = data['name'];
var firstName = name.split(' ')[0];
```